# Responsive bootstrap not working for Lumia windows 8 Phones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have included

```
@-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
@viewport           { width: device-width; }
```

in my styles.

and this in my head

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {

        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style")
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(
            "@@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
          )
        )
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle)
    }

</script>
```

Note that the @@ is because it is in a Razor file and I have verifyed the client get send a single @.

but the page is still not rended as expected. Cant figure out whats missing.

The output can be viewed here. http://www.s-innovations.net/Blog

Comment: for what it's worth my Lumia seems to have a mind of its own here. It will set the viewport to the correct size about half the time I load the page. Imagine that, even mobile IE sucks...

Comment: I have done this half a year ago on a lumia 920, I have a 1020 now, and now I just cant get it to work on either